# assign a unique color to a array number in java

Tags: java

hi guys im new to programming this is my code

```
for (int i = 0; i < V; i++)
        System.out.print(value[i] +" ");
    System.out.println();
```

value of "i" are numbers , instead of printing value of "i" I want to print a unique color for each value for example if this is the value: "1 2 1 1 3"
i want to print: "red blue red red green" 
how can i do this?

Comment: if you just started with java, try to search if-else statement

Comment: thanks for comment and help. someone suggest switch case and it is working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `switch` to choose the color

```
private String getColor(int num) {
    switch (num) {
        case 1: return "red";
        case 2: return "blue";
        case 3: return "green";
        default: return "";
    }
}

for (int i = 0 ; i < V ; ++i) {
    System.out.print(getColor(value[i]) +" ");
}
System.out.println();
```

Comment: thanks for your reply it is really simple learning

Answer (score 2):

```
HashMap<Integer, String> colors = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
colors.put(1, "red");
colors.put(2, "blue");
colors.put(3, "green");

for (int i=0; i<V; i++) {
  System.out.println(colors.get(values[i]));
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply.